# Non-existence of an element in a splitting field -- obvious, but hard to prove

Tags: galois-theory, splitting-field

I've been working through some problems in Dummit and Foote and have in general been struggling with rigorously finding the degree of a field extension. Intuitively the answer is usually obvious because the adjoined roots are some how "independent" of one another. For instance, how can I find the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[8]{5})$? It's obviously 16 but my issue is that I can't prove that $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[8]{5})$. Or perhaps there is another approach?

Comment: How can it be obvious and simultaneously not easy to prove?

Comment: I'm actually not sure if you're mocking me because 1) in the previous sentence I explained "Intuitively the answer is usually obvious because the adjoined roots are some how "independent" of one another", and 2) there are so many examples where the result of a theorem is "obvious" (in the sense of "the result couldn't possibly be anything else") but is deceptively hard to prove.

Comment: Yes, your intuition suggests that $\sqrt2$ is not an element of the octic extension field, but intuition cannot always be trusted. For example $\sqrt2$ is an element of the splitting field of $p(x)=x^8-5$. In this case the intuitiion is correct though. I would use one the following approaches. A) With Galois theory in place it is not too difficult to show that $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$ is the only quadratic subfield of $\Bbb{Q}(\root8\of 5)$. Then you only need to prove that $\sqrt2\notin\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$.

Comment: B) Without Galois theory you can do the following. You undoubtedly know the zeros of $p(x)$. Therefore you can check that none of the factors of $p(x)$ have coefficients in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$. That task is simplified by the fact that most factors of $p(x)$ don't have real coefficients. Anyway, this way you can show that $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$. Therefore
$$[\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\root8\of5):\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)]=8,$$ and it's all sunshine.

Comment: Show $5^{1/8}\notin Q(2^{1/2}))$.

Comment: You need to show that $X^8-5$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2\,)$, and in spite of what @i.m.soloveichik says, this is just a bit more difficult than showing that $5^{1/8}\notin\Bbb Q(\sqrt2\,)$. However, it happens that $5$ is still prime in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt2\,]$, so that Eisenstein applies to $X^8-5$, and all is well.